# optimize the display of a list grails datatable

Tags: grails, datatables

I use grails 2.4.4 and I have a list that contains thousands of data, I want to display it on a datatable just loading the first 10 lines and the rest of the line will be managed server side Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created your account. See: [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question is likely to be closed because it is not clear what you want and what your problem is. Please always include all the relevant code (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) when posting a question and be very specific as to what problem you are having.

Comment: So you need to use datatables in your gsp view with a paginated Ajax source making calls to a controller action which will perform the query, any filtering and sorting and return the json result that datatables expects..  Check this tutorial to guide you through:  https://opensource.com/article/18/9/using-grails-jquery-and-datatables